# Unsure why I'm getting error MSB6006: "mt.exe" exited with code 31. on first build of solution after a change is made in code

Tags: c++

however after I build the solution for a second time the problem disappears. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I ma also experiencing some other strange symptoms, however I am not certain if they are related. I am able to toggle from .cpp files to .h files but not the other way round. When trying to got to a function definition for a .h file I get the error pop up window saying "A definition for the symbol 'functionname' could not be located. Any idea what could be going wrong here. This problem is consistent in every project not just one specific project.

Comment: mt.exe has an unenviable job, it needs to modify an executable file right after it is written to the disk by the linker.  It often loses the battle against anti-malware.  You need to add an exclusion for your project directories.